# Which IPN variable to store and how - Paypal IPN

Tags: php, sql, paypal-ipn

This is more of a design issue.

There are number of [paypal IPN variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables) that are available as confirmation of payment of the transaction. There are a lot of them. My question is, how do i store them in the database?

1. Should all of them be insert in one row in a table, lets say sold_item.
2. Or store them across multiple tables and build relationship between them.
3. Should I store *all* variables that are available in IPN transaction or do only important ones?

My plan is, you are register user of my site. You list an item, someone buy it. I get the payment notification (IPN) then I send you an email, your item is sold. I want to store the information of the transaction that I receive from Paypal.

Any help insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Should all of them be insert in one row in a table, lets say sold_item.

   *Well, anything that works for you. Be sure to save the fields which are very important in your part.
   If you think storing all data as a row is a tenous task, then you can serialize it.*
2. Or store them across multiple tables and build relationship between them.

   *Much better :)*
3. Should I store all variables that are available in IPN transaction or do only important ones?

   *Well, if you have custom variables you can save it too. If you feel that you only need the important data, then
   nevermind the less important, you can save some space in your database too :)